# menu bar where the width of the text is variable

Tags: css

I need to know how do I get the menu where the background depends upon the text entered. As in the image, the background gets expended irrespective of the text in the menu item. Also the sides of the background image should not get distorted.The image is [here](http://i25.tinypic.com/4kv5p3.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still tend to use the sliding doors technique for this kind of thing.
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Although there is probably a newer and more elegant solution these days.

Comment: ya thats done.. but its mentioned like there is a better way available... anyways this is working now... thanks... i was in fact searching for that BETTER OPTION !!!!!!